# Passing String and list to multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

So I am trying to send a list and a string variable to my multiprocessing method but the string is split into list

Here is my Program :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product

combs = "1a 1A 2a 2A 3@ 3$".split()

def mword(list, base): 
    tag = base[0:2] + comb +base[4:7]  # Error at this line
    return tag

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Enter Sample word")
    base = input()
    p = Pool()
    result = p.starmap(mword, product(combs, str(base)))
    p.close()
    p.join()



> INPUT : QWERTYU  
> Expected Output : 
  QW1aTYU #keep changing 3rd and 4th Character
  QW1ATYU
> OUTPUT : 
  Q1A
  W1A .. so on
```

I have also tried :

> ''.join(base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

product expects 2 lists. You are passing it a list of combs and a string which is a *list of chars*. So the result is each char of the string and each of the combs.

To make this work as expected pass product a list where the string is the only item it it knows not to cut up the string into individual chars.

```
result = p.starmap(mword, product(combs, [str(base)]))
```